# json-server : how to write correct endpoints

Tags: express, json-server

If I have a json file like this :

```
 {
   "users": {
     "count": 157,
     "rows": [...data]
   },
   "gifts": { ...}
}
```

How can I write endpoints to get the users.count and the users.rows ?
thanks for feedback

Answer (score 0):

No need for such structure, using _start and _end , I also get an X-Total-Count: 14 in the header ...